# Outer vertices of a SVG image loaded externally

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

I wanted to get the Outermost vertices of a SVG image loaded to a webpage. is there any Javascript based library functions which can be used to solve the above problem?

I tried snap.svg library. but i could get only bbox of svg. but i want the exact vertices lying outermost of the svg.

my Code for loading svg and getting bbox

```
    var s = Snap("#svg");
    Snap.load("myTestImg.svg", onSVGLoaded);

    function onSVGLoaded(data) {
        s.append(data);
        s.node.getBBox();
    }
```

my svg code looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentScriptType="application/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css" height="119.0" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.1" viewBox="-118.812089225497 -118.812089225497 237.624178450994 242.624178450994" width="119.0" zoomAndPan="magnify"><g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.00028525" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, -1)">
<g id="NewFeatureType">
  <g id="Halo">
    <ellipse cx="-0.000118878670036793" cy="0.000118878465145826" rx="69.9997622428617" ry="69.9997622428617" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(240,248,255);stroke-width:0;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <polyline points="-49.5,49.5 49.5,-49.5" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(240,248,255);stroke-width:0;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <polyline points="49.5,49.5 -49.5,-49.5" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(240,248,255);stroke-width:0;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <polyline points="82.14,82.35 -81.42,82.35 -81.42,-81.57 82.14,-81.57 82.14,82.35" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(240,248,255);stroke-width:0;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <polyline points="-82.62,-2.18 -82.62,-2.18" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(240,248,255);stroke-width:0;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <polyline points="81.19,-0.54 81.19,-0.54" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(240,248,255);stroke-width:0;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <polyline points="1.93,-82.25 1.93,-82.25" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(240,248,255);stroke-width:0;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <polyline points="0.14,79.5 0.14,79.5" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(240,248,255);stroke-width:0;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
  </g>
  <g id="Org">
    <ellipse cx="-0.000118878670036793" cy="0.000118878465145826" rx="69.9997622428617" ry="69.9997622428617" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:5;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <polyline points="-49.5,49.5 49.5,-49.5" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:5;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <polyline points="49.5,49.5 -49.5,-49.5" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:5;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <polyline points="82.14,82.35 -81.42,82.35 -81.42,-81.57 82.14,-81.57 82.14,82.35" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:5;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <polyline points="-82.62,-2.18 -82.62,-2.18" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:5;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <polyline points="81.19,-0.54 81.19,-0.54" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:5;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <polyline points="1.93,-82.25 1.93,-82.25" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:5;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <polyline points="0.14,79.5 0.14,79.5" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:5;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-linecap:round"/>
    <ellipse cx="0" cy="0" rx="116.312089225497" ry="116.312089225497" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1;stroke-opacity:0"/>
  </g>
</g>
```

please provide a solution , i am new to svg image processing.

Comment: Define “outermost vertices”. Do you just mean whatever point has the largest distance from the “middle” of the SVG, or what?

Comment: yes. if the image is of a rectangle shape, then all 4 vertices must be returned.

Comment: And what would need to be returned if the image contained an oval shape, offset slightly from the middle and, say, rotated by 13 degrees counter-clockwise …?

Comment: For now, solution needed for shapes that consists of only straight lines.

Comment: Even a “straight line” could have any sort of transformations, rotations etc. applied. I think you are massively underestimating the complexity of what you are dealing with here.

Comment: All the SVGs i'm working with has the attribute transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, -1)"